# How to vibrate iPhone when the app is in the background

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, vibration, iphone-vibrate

This code vibrates iPhone

```
AudioToolbox.SystemSound.Vibrate.PlaySystemSound();
```

How can I vibrate iPhone when my app is in the background ?

Comment: Likely not possible due to Apple's 'non-invasive' requirements for apps, however I defer to those who actually know the language.